# Computing a(k)+a(j) when k is not equal to j

Tags: matlab, loops, vector, sum

Given a vector `a`, I'd like to compute the sums of `a(k)+a(j)`, where `k` isn't equal to `j`, separately for each `k`. I wrote code that is supposed to do this, but since the outputs differ from what I expect, I realize it isn't working correctly.

```
a=[1 2 3 4]

sumj=0;
b=0;

for k=1:4
    for j=1:4       
        if j~=k
           sumj = a(k)+ a(j)
        end    
    end
   b=b+sumj
end
```

In the 1<sup>st</sup> iteration of the outer loop, when `k=1`, I expect these values in the console:

```
sumj=a(k)+a(j)=a(1)+a(2)=3
sumj=a(k)+a(j)=a(1)+a(3)=4
sumj=a(k)+a(j)=a(1)+a(4)=5
b=3+4+5=12
```

Similarly, in the 2<sup>nd</sup> iteration, when `k=2`:

```
sumj=3
sumj=5
sumj=6
b=3+5+6=14
```

In the 3<sup>rd</sup>:

```
sumj=4
sumj=5
sumj=7
b=4+5+7=16
```

In the 4<sup>th</sup>:

```
sumj=5
sumj=6
sumj=7
b=5+6+7=18
```

but instead of the above I'm getting:

```
sumj=3,sumj=4,sumj=5,b=5 (b shouldn't be 5,it should be 12)
sumj=3,sumj=5,sumj=6,b=5+6=11 (b shouldn't be 11,it should be 14)
sumj=4,sumj=5,sumj=7,b=5+6+7=18 (b shouldn't be 18,it should be 16)
sumj=5,sumj=6,sumj=7,b=5+6+7+7=25 (b shouldn't be 25,it should be 18)
```

How should I modify the code to get the result I want?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question was badly formatted and it was very difficult to understand what was going on. You could get an answer much faster if your post was properly [formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). I have fixed it for you _this time_, but next time please try to make your post as clear and as readable as you can. See also [ask].

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is because you overwrite the value of `sumj` in the innermost loop without storing it. It should be

```
% Option 1
sumj = sumj + a(k)+ a(j) 
% Option 2
sumj = a(k)+ a(j) 
b=b+sumj % i.e. right after, not outside the loop.
```

To conclude, with minimal modifications to your code::

```
a = [1 2 3 4];   

for k=1:4
    b=0;
    for j=1:4       
        if j~=k
            sumj = a(k)+ a(j);
            b=b+sumj;
        end    
    end
    b        
end
```

Furthermore, we can get rid of the unnecessary `sumj`,

```
a = [1 2 3 4];

for k=1:4
    b=0;
    for j=1:4       
        if j~=k
            b = b + a(k)+ a(j);
        end    
    end        
    b
end
```

Or we can also vectorize this:

```
b = a + a.';                  % This creates a symmetric matrix
b = sum(b - diag(diag(b)),2); % This clears the main diagonal and sums
% b = [12;14;16;18]
```